# How to integrate $\frac{1}{1 + a^2 \tan^2x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Can you please help me out with evaluating this integral?

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1 + a^2 \tan^2x}dx$$

Comment: @Stefan I tried replacing $\tan x$ with $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$ but arrived at another integral that I don't know how to evaluate. I also tried to find some substitution, but couldn't find any that would help me get rid of $x$.

Comment: There is a substitution that can convert any trig integral into a rational function integral.  If all else fails, use it.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_o^{2\pi}\frac1{1+a^2\tan^2(x)}\mathrm{d}x
&=4\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac1{1+a^2\tan^2(x)}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=4\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+a^2u^2}\mathrm{d}\arctan(u)\\
&=4\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+a^2u^2}\frac1{1+u^2}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac4{a^2-1}\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{a^2}{1+a^2u^2}-\frac1{1+u^2}\right)\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac4{a^2-1}\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{a^2}{1+a^2u^2}\mathrm{d}u-\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+u^2}\mathrm{d}u\right)\\
&=\frac4{a^2-1}\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{|a|}{1+u^2}\mathrm{d}u-\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+u^2}\mathrm{d}u\right)\\
&=\frac4{|a|+1}\int_0^\infty\frac1{1+u^2}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{|a|+1}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + a^2 \tan^2x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1 + a^2 \tan^2x}\frac{\sec^2(x)}{1 +  \tan^2x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{(1+au^2)(1+u^2)}$$

Comment: @Paul: If you take $u=\tan(t)$, you will get the same result as the last fraction again.